# Find packages that cause docker daemon to restart before apt upgrade?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, availability

I have an ubuntu-server (versions 18 & 20) and want to update all packages on my machine except for the docker daemon.

After pinning the docker daemon version and running the `apt upgrade`, the service still got unavailable through some other dependency that got updated in the process.

How can I find out which packages cause the docker daemon to restart/become unavailable before running an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pinning the packages, set the docker packages on hold.

```
sudo apt-mark hold containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli
```

I've been using this on docker machines for years without problems. When I want to do the upgrades, I remove the hold, upgrade the packages and set them back on hold.

This has the additional advantage that apt tells you when updates are available, but not installed.

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  containerd.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```